# Harvesting rasters from GeoServer --empty string error

Tags: geoserver, metadata, geonetwork

we are using GeoNetwork  v.3.12.7.0 and we try to harvest rasters from Geoserver v.2.23.1.

While some rasters can be harvested successfully, we have errors for some others (see below for the log). We fill the metadata in exactly the same way so the error message for us is obscure as it says *Failed to load metadata document for layer 'L Annual Probability LogN'. Error is: 'For input string: ""',* without giving us any clue on the name of this field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
2023-10-12T16:17:41,790+0200 INFO  [RecommendationITU_R_P840_9] - Starting harvesting of RecommendationITU-R.P840-9 
2023-10-12T16:17:41,805+0200 INFO  [RecommendationITU_R_P840_9] - Started harvesting from node : RecommendationITU-R.P840-9 (OgcWxSHarvester) 
2023-10-12T16:17:41,805+0200 INFO  [RecommendationITU_R_P840_9] - Retrieving remote metadata information for : RecommendationITU-R.P840-9 
2023-10-12T16:17:41,962+0200 INFO  [RecommendationITU_R_P840_9] -   - Number of layers, featureTypes, Coverages or process found : 31 
2023-10-12T16:17:41,962+0200 INFO  [RecommendationITU_R_P840_9] -   - Loading layer: L Annual Probability LogN with UUID 1eab6e15768a7bd565df238a70c0681a8338a1a1 (hash of capabilities URL + layer name). 
2023-10-12T16:17:41,977+0200 WARN  [RecommendationITU_R_P840_9] -   - Failed to load metadata document for layer 'L Annual Probability LogN'. Error is: 'For input string: ""'
```

Comment: does the other layer have spaces in it's name too?

Comment: yes, all layers have spaces in their names

Comment: This error "For input string" is usually thrown when trying to convert a string to a number. In this case the string is empty. Maybe you can guess where there is an empty or not present value that should be present or be a number.

Comment: The usual suspect is a bounding box component.